# why my code is not working for input greater than 12?

Tags: c++

There is no problem when I input a number smaller than 12 but when I input something bigger the code returns with no output without any error. What's the problem?

Sample output I am getting -

Sample 1 -

```
1 13
Press any key to continue....
```

Sample 2 -

```
1 12
27720
Press any key to continue....
```

Sample 3 -

```
1 10
2520
Press any key to continue....
```

**More Information -**
Actually this is an Question from project Euler's Hackerrank Contest -
[Project Euler #5 - Smallest Multiple](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler005/problem)

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible(divisible with no remainder) by all of the numbers from  to N?
>
> Input Format
>
> First line contains T that denotes the number of test cases. This is followed by T lines, each containing an integer, N.
>
> Constraints -
>
> ```
> 1 <= T <= 10
> 1 <= N <= 40
> ```
>
> Output Format
>
> Print the required answer for each test case.
>
> Sample Input 0
>
> ```
> 2
> 3
> 10
> ```
>
> Sample Output 0
>
> ```
> 6
> 2520
> ```

**Here is my solution -**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

long smallest_multiple(int n, long num){
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if(num % i != 0){
            while(num % i != 0){
                num++;
                return smallest_multiple(n, num);
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
}

int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        long num = 2;
        long int ans = smallest_multiple(n, num);
        cout << ans << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can you tell me what's going wrong and what can be done?
P.S. Noob here, Please explain step by step. I'm just starting out.

Comment: What debugging have you tried ?

Comment: `what's going wrong` The depth of the recursion is equal to the end result. That grows quickly, and you are overflowing the stack. `what can be done` Find a better algorithm, or at least change the recursion to a loop.

Comment: Your loop body is equivalent to `if (num % i != 0) return smallest_multiple(n, num+1);`.

Comment: see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714), [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: An efficient solution consists in considering prime numbers p[i] less or equal to N, and then to calculate the power associated to each prime. For example, for N = 13, `num = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13;`

Comment: Project Euler problems can only rarely be solved using brute force algorithms. (That description does not look like it is from the Project Euler site, though.)

Comment: Please post outputs as text, not screenshots

Comment: It could work with a bigger data type but I don't know if it will be proccessed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- **What was going wrong** -
  The data was growing so quickly because of recursion, that it was overflowing the stack.
- **What I did** -

Found a better algorithm that's not using recursion -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        long n;
        cin >> n;
        long div = 2;

        while(div <= sqrt(n)){
            if(n % div == 0){
                n  /= div;
            }
            else{
                div++;
            }
        }

        cout << n << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```